# Find the inflection points in the graph

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image]

The question is which of the $x$-values of the given points are inflection points of the function $f(x)$ itself?

I chose $C,F$ and $H$ because at this point the $f'(x)$ is zero. But my answer was wrong. Why ? is it only $C$ & $F$ ?

Comment: In $C,F,H$, $f'(x)=0$ for sure. But, in $H$ there is something very different, isn't ? Try to identify.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici it started positive and ended positive.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici So it is just C & F?

Comment: Inflection points corresponds to $f''(x)=0$ that is to say maximum or minimum of $f'(x)$, isn't ?

Comment: Now I'm lost because when I did these problems, I just look at the graph and determine the inflection points ... if I was doing derivatives, then I would have to determine which of the points are increasing or decreasing (first derivative) or concavity (second derivative)

Comment: exactly using second derivative we are  checking if critical points are maximum or minimum points

Comment: so we need to find the concavity. 

What I am trying to say is .. is the OP's question just look at the graph and find inflection points or ... find first and second derivatives and whichever is 0 there is inflection?

Comment: -___-! We have to find the second derivative of the graph... using the graph method don't we?  Ick I hated those problems when I took Calculus I.

Comment: :D :D to be honest nobody loves :D  just we need to use it :D

Comment: ^^ @.@! I am asking a question here :( why the chatting :/

Comment: :( all I can remember is B E G H (if I draw a horizontal line on those points) would be 0, or am I confusing that with slope fields XD

Comment: It's just a friendly Mathematical chat ;)!

Comment: @user157908  there is alternative  solution which you may need to  do yourself,it seems that this function is continuous,so you may need using straight lines recover original function,that means sketch straight  lines and then integrate it,finally you will get original function,then take it's second derivative and make set to equal 0

Comment: @usukidoll lol my homework will end soon :(

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=go8KsoLfiD0 please see it

Comment: @datodatuashvili so it will be B, G, E without the H ?

Comment: including i think

Comment: isn't that for finding the derivative with the graph method I have to draw a reflection of the graph. Like that point A for $f'(x)$ is up, so the $f''(x)$ version will have it down?

Comment: Inflection points are where the concavity changes sign (i.e. where the first derivative changes from increasing to decreasing or vice versa). That being said, should the inflection points not then be B,E,G,H.

Answer (score 3):

Inflection points are points where the first derivative changes from increasing to decreasing or vice versa. 
Equivalently we can view them as local minimums/maximums of $f'(x)$.

Wiki page of Inflection Points: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_points

From the graph we can then see that the inflection points are $B,E,G,H$.

Answer (score 0):

inflection point is where  second derivatives are zero,so you may  review to check where is second derivative zero

http://calculus.nipissingu.ca/tutorials/curves.html

[image]

inflection points

Comment: But he is asking for the inflection point of the f(x) when the given graph is the f'(x)

Comment: The question isn't asking if the graph is increasing or decreasing (first derivative). The question isn't asking for concavity either (second derivative)

Comment: but related for inflection points,it should be also considered